# How to use JavaCV from SBT (Simple Build Tool) in Scala?

Tags: scala, opencv, sbt, javacv

how to use JavaCV from SBT (Simple Build Tool) in Scala? I need to use JavaCV so I can write a Scala application using this.

Simple Build Tool is here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/

JavaCV is here: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an SBT plugin that solves most of this for you in 1 line; no need to set up native libraries etc because this will do it all for you.

https://github.com/lloydmeta/sbt-opencv

Usage:

Add the following in `project/plugins.sbt`:

`addSbtPlugin("com.beachape" % "sbt-opencv" % "1.2")`

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your build.sbt file.

```
resolvers += "JavaCV maven repo" at "http://maven2.javacv.googlecode.com/git/"

libraryDepedencies += "com.googlecode.javacv" % "javacv" % "0.2"
```

This should pull down javacv for you, as well as any dependencies. Note you will still need to have all the native libraries set up like javacv details, this only gets the jars for your project.

Comment: Hi Ivan, My pastebin is here - http://pastebin.com/FmJSTREX - it has the error [error] error while loading opencv_core, Missing dependency 'class com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.Properties', required by /Users/orsa/.ivy2/cache/com.googlecode.javacv/javacv/jars/javacv-0.2.jar(com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.class)
[error] one error found

Comment: I added javacpp.jar
javacv-macosx-x86_64.jar
javacv.jar
to my lib directory and it compiles and run's if I also remove all the other SBT directives. So, my OpenCV is installed correctly, but I still can't get the SBT to work correctly downloading the right artifacts

Comment: I grabbed Ivan's build.sbt and main from his pastebin and ran them through sbt.  I can see that sbt is downloading the expected JARs to the .ivy2 cache.  Like Ivan, I was able to get it to work by copying the JARs to the sbt project's lib directory.  I'm a Maven/Ivy novice, but my guess is the problem is that the javacpp ivy XML doesn't state a dependency on javacv. I don't know enough to help you work around that.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure, I'll have a go soon with that pastebin example

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on there. I think you might want to post on the simple-build-tool google group about it.

Comment: In the end - I put the JAR into the lib directory rather than using this, SBT allows any JAR in the lib directory.